# При горизонтальном скроллинге правый блок не заезжал на фиксированный левый блок

Tags: css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы при горизонтальном скроллинге правый блок не заезжал на фиксированный левый блок. Пример - https://codepen.io/tol_drew/pen/QWqBBPZ

**HTML:**

```
<div class='dashboard'>
<div class="dashboard-nav">
    <header><a href="#!" class="menu-toggle"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a><a href="#"
                                                                               class="brand-logo"><i
            class="fas fa-anchor"></i> <span>BRAND</span></a></header>
    <nav class="dashboard-nav-list"><a href="#" class="dashboard-nav-item"><i class="fas fa-home"></i>
        Home </a><a
            href="#" class="dashboard-nav-item active"><i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i> dashboard
    </a><a
            href="#" class="dashboard-nav-item"><i class="fas fa-file-upload"></i> Upload </a>
        <div class='dashboard-nav-dropdown'><a href="#!" class="dashboard-nav-item dashboard-nav-dropdown-toggle"><i
                class="fas fa-photo-video"></i> Media </a>
            <div class='dashboard-nav-dropdown-menu'><a href="#"
                                                        class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-item">All</a><a
                    href="#" class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-item">Recent</a><a
                    href="#" class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-item">Images</a><a
                    href="#" class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-item">Video</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class='dashboard-nav-dropdown'><a href="#!" class="dashboard-nav-item dashboard-nav-dropdown-toggle"><i
                class="fas fa-users"></i> Users </a>
            <div class='dashboard-nav-dropdown-menu'><a href="#"
                                                        class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-item">All</a><a
                    href="#" class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-item">Subscribed</a><a
                    href="#"
                    class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-item">Non-subscribed</a><a
                    href="#" class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-item">Banned</a><a
                    href="#" class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-item">New</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class='dashboard-nav-dropdown'><a href="#!" class="dashboard-nav-item dashboard-nav-dropdown-toggle"><i
                class="fas fa-money-check-alt"></i> Payments </a>
            <div class='dashboard-nav-dropdown-menu'><a href="#"
                                                        class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-item">All</a><a
                    href="#" class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-item">Recent</a><a
                    href="#" class="dashboard-nav-dropdown-item"> Projections</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="dashboard-nav-item"><i class="fas fa-cogs"></i> Settings </a><a
                href="#" class="dashboard-nav-item"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> Profile </a>
      <div class="nav-item-divider"></div>
      <a
                href="#" class="dashboard-nav-item"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i> Logout </a>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class='dashboard-app'>
    <header class='dashboard-toolbar'><a href="#!" class="menu-toggle"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a></header>
    <div class='dashboard-content'>
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='card'>
                <div class='card-header'>
                    <h1>Welcome back Jim</h1>
                </div>
                <div class='card-body'>
                    <p>Your account type is: Administratorbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    :root {
    --font-family-sans-serif: "Open Sans", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont,
    "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji",
    "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
}

*, *::before, *::after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.15;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

nav {
    display: block;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: "Open Sans", -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI",
    Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji",
    "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #515151;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #e9edf4;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

p {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

a {
    color: #3f84fc;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}

a:hover {
    color: #0458eb;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, .h1, .h2, .h3, .h4, .h5, .h6 {
    font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 1.2;
}

h1, .h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    font-weight: normal;
}

.card {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-clip: border-box;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    border-radius: 0;
}

.card-body {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 1.25rem;
}

.card-header {
    padding: 0.75rem 1.25rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.125);
    text-align: center;
}

.dashboard {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.dashboard-app {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-box-flex: 2;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 2;
    -ms-flex-positive: 2;
    flex-grow: 2;
    margin-top: 84px;
}

.dashboard-content {
    -webkit-box-flex: 2;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 2;
    -ms-flex-positive: 2;
    flex-grow: 2;
    padding: 25px;
}

.dashboard-nav {
    min-width: 238px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #373193;
}

.dashboard-compact .dashboard-nav {
    display: none;
}

.dashboard-nav header {
    min-height: 84px;
    padding: 8px 27px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.dashboard-nav header .menu-toggle {
    display: none;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.dashboard-nav a {
    color: #515151;
}

.dashboard-nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dashboard-nav {
    background-color: #443ea2;
}

.dashboard-nav a {
    color: #fff;
}

.brand-logo {
    font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    color: #515151;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.brand-logo:focus, .brand-logo:active, .brand-logo:hover {
    color: #dbdbdb;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.brand-logo i {
    color: #d2d1d1;
    font-size: 27px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.dashboard-nav-list {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.dashboard-nav-item {
    min-height: 56px;
    padding: 8px 20px 8px 70px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    transition: ease-out 0.5s;
}

.dashboard-nav-item i {
    width: 36px;
    font-size: 19px;
    margin-left: -40px;
}

.dashboard-nav-item:hover {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04);
}

.active {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.dashboard-nav-dropdown {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.dashboard-nav-dropdown.show {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04);
}

.dashboard-nav-dropdown.show > .dashboard-nav-dropdown-toggle {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.dashboard-nav-dropdown.show > .dashboard-nav-dropdown-toggle:after {
    -webkit-transform: none;
    -o-transform: none;
    transform: none;
}

.dashboard-nav-dropdown.show > .dashboard-nav-dropdown-menu {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}

.dashboard-nav-dropdown-toggle:after {
    content: "";
    margin-left: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-top: 5px solid rgba(81, 81, 81, 0.8);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.dashboard-nav .dashboard-nav-dropdown-toggle:after {
    border-top-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.72);
}

.dashboard-nav-dropdown-menu {
    display: none;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.dashboard-nav-dropdown-item {
    min-height: 40px;
    padding: 8px 20px 8px 70px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: ease-out 0.5s;
}

.dashboard-nav-dropdown-item:hover {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04);
}

.menu-toggle {
    position: relative;
    width: 42px;
    height: 42px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: #443ea2;
}

.menu-toggle:hover, .menu-toggle:active, .menu-toggle:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #875de5;
}

.menu-toggle i {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.dashboard-toolbar {
    min-height: 84px;
    background-color: #dfdfdf;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 8px 27px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.nav-item-divider {
    height: 1px;
    margin: 1rem 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: rgba(236, 238, 239, 0.3);
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .dashboard-app {
        margin-left: 238px;
    }

    .dashboard-compact .dashboard-app {
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}


@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .dashboard-content {
        padding: 15px 0px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .dashboard-nav {
        display: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: 1070;
    }

    .dashboard-nav.mobile-show {
        display: block;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .dashboard-nav header .menu-toggle {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .dashboard-toolbar {
        left: 238px;
    }

    .dashboard-compact .dashboard-toolbar {
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

**js**:

```
    const mobileScreen = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 990px )");
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".dashboard-nav-dropdown-toggle").click(function () {
        $(this).closest(".dashboard-nav-dropdown")
            .toggleClass("show")
            .find(".dashboard-nav-dropdown")
            .removeClass("show");
        $(this).parent()
            .siblings()
            .removeClass("show");
    });
    $(".menu-toggle").click(function () {
        if (mobileScreen.matches) {
            $(".dashboard-nav").toggleClass("mobile-show");
        } else {
            $(".dashboard").toggleClass("dashboard-compact");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Скрины конечно это круто. Но без примера я не думаю что кто то сможет помочь. Думаю, что когда происходит скролл, окну (таблице) добавляются какие то классы, смотрите через инспектор. Можно попробовать вычитать ширину фиксированного блока из ширины таблицы (которая заезжает).

Comment: добавил в вопрос стили. Во время скрола не заметил добавление каких-то классов

Comment: Вы должны выложить стили к вашему примеру. Так совсем не понятно что происходит. Нету информации. Обычно, для быстрой помощи использует мини-пример. В мини-примере воспроизводят ошибку и выкладывают  исходники и описывают попытки. Как минимум нужно иметь живой пример перед глазами.

Comment: вот пример - https://codepen.io/tol_drew/pen/QWqBBPZ

Comment: body > .dashboard .dashboard-nav {
    z-index: 10;
}
body > .dashboard .dashboard-app {
    z-index: 1;
}

Comment: А если скролл перенести внутрь контейнера с большим содержимимым? `.dashboard-app{overflow-x:auto}`

Comment: Спасибо. Воспользовался советом Zombotron